# Conemu no longer treating vim cursors properly

Tags: vim, console, conemu

I am using vim through conemu and it's strangely stopped putting a rectangle for normal mode. Instead it puts an underscore, which it also does for insert mode. I have reset all conemu settings and tried everything, I can't understand this bizarre problem after using it fine for years. If I open vim using the native Windows 7 console it works like it's supposed to with a rectangle for normal mode. Another thing it's doing strangely is when I press backspace in insert mode, it doesn't reflect the deletion of the words on the screen immediately, they are still visible.

It actually opens properly in conemu also when I run it from the start box in Windows 7. But when I try opening it from a conemu prompt, it doesn't work, it always used to before. I also tried it with administrator privileges with the same outcome.

edit: I fixed it by changing the order of items in "path" in environmental variables. I still don't understand why conemu treated things different to the ordinary command prompt since I thought they would be fed the same thing.

Comment: Your question and solution(?) aren't clear. Is your question actual?

Comment: I think my question and later solution are clear enough. If you suspect a question of not being in good faith then you should either ignore or complain to stackexchange.

Comment: Without exact example of changes in PATH variable your question doesn't look like fair complain.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. What did you have to change in the `PATH`?